# Endpoint returns false on android devices lower than 5.0 and true on higher devices

Tags: c#, android, rest, api

This is giving me some real concern. I have an endpoint, which works well. Tested on Postman. 
However, when it is called on android devices lower than 5.0, it gives a 200 response but never validates what is meant to be validated, returning the key parameter as false.
On higher devices, it always validates. 
I have subjected these devices to same conditions. e.g internet connection...except for the device version. This is actually strange. Can anyone please help?

Code

```
@Override
            protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError){
                if(volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null){
                    VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
                    volleyError = error;
                }

                return volleyError;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Authorization", "bearer " +token);
//                header.put("WWW-Authenticate", "xBasic realm='fake'");
                return header;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", merchant_id);
                params.put("acceptInterCard", acceptInterCard);
                params.put("longitude", longitude);
                params.put("latitude", latitude);
//                params.put("mccCode", mccCode);

                Log.e("params-", params.get("id"));

                return params;
            }

        };



        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                50000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

//        stringRequest.getHeaders();

        RequestManager.getRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: This is actually really vague. There's so much to guess about what you are doing that answering this question can only be speculative, at best. To improve this, you need to add the code you're making the bad requests with, and the code you answer with. You might also consider setting up a web-monitoring proxy and setting it as the HTTP proxy on your android devices (such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)) so that you can see what's actually happening differently between the successes and the failures. As it stands, my only option here is a close vote. Sorry.

Comment: @spender...Cool man. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler - fiddler hasn't changed that much over the years, so this should see you good.

Comment: Thanks. Just pasted the code.